# How to select specific element based on a part of its attribute with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

This issue seems very easy and I have found some threads about it but those solutions don't work when we have multiple tabs more the 2 tabs to select from.

Example:
[image]

So in this case when I use (goal is to select the tab "Routing"):

```
...    
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Test", "Test - tab");
        this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
    });
...
```

It will select the first not selected tab "Data" and not tab "Routing"!

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, CSS selectors are your friend for example with a specific attribute selector matching the content of the attribute:

```
this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[href*="tabIndex.value=\'3\'"]');
```

or

```
var i = 3;
this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[href*="tabIndex.value=\''+i+'\'"]');
```